# I cannot fetch a post in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, post, fetch-api, crud

I have a question about the code. Probably the solution is very simple, but I'm taking the first step in JavaScript and it is not obvious to me.

I have some backend ready, postman sending POST is ok. So backend is fine.

I wrote a simple application in which after pressing the button saves the given data in the database.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work with the debugger, everything is fine. However, by clicking the button in the view something is wrong and no fetch is called. The object is not saving to the database.

Please help.

```js
Api = function() {
  this.header = new Headers({
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
};

Api.prototype.buildUrl = function(id) {
  return "http://localhost:3000/db/shop_name/" + id;
};

Api.prototype.post = function(id, data) {

  const urlPost = api.buildUrl(id.value);
  return fetch(urlPost, {
      method: "post",
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: this.header
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      console.log("Dodałem użytkownika:");
      console.log(res);
    })
};

Api.prototype.get = function(id) {
  //const urlGet = api.buildUrl(id);
  return fetch(id, {
      method: "GET",
    })
    .then(resp => {
      alert(resp.json());

      return resp.json();
    })
};
Api.prototype.getAlll = function() {
  return fetch(url, {
      method: "GET"
    })
    .then(resp => {
      alert(resp.json());
      return resp.json()
    })
};

Api.prototype.update = function(id, data) {
  const url = api.buildUrl(id);
  return fetch(url, {
      method: "PUT",
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    .then(resp => {
      return resp.json()
        .catch(error => {
          let notFound = "The server can not find requested resource";
          document.getElementById("stars").innerHTML = notFound + error.status;
        })
    })
};


Api.prototype.addProduct = function(id, data) {
  return this.post(id, data);
};

Api.prototype.deleteProduct = function(id) {
  return this.delete(id);
};

Api.prototype.updateProduct = function(id, data) {
  return this.update(id, data);
};

Api.prototype.getProduct = function(id) {
  return this.get(id);
};
Api.prototype.getAllProducts = function() {
  return this.getAlll;
};

const Main = function() {
  this.id = document.getElementById("id");
  this.addCount = document.getElementById("count");
  this.addName = document.getElementById("name");
  this.addPrice = document.getElementById("price");
};


Main.prototype.add = function() {
  // const ido = this.id.value;
  const data = {
    "price": this.addPrice.value,
    "name": this.addName.value,
    "count": this.addCount.value,
  };
  //  let id = api.buildUrl(this.id.value);
  api.addProduct(this.id, data);
};


Main.prototype.update = function() {
  const data = {
    "price": this.price,
    "name": this.name,
    "count": this.count,
  };
  api.updateProduct(id, data);
};

Main.prototype.delete = function() {
  let id = api.buildUrl(this.id);
  api.deleteProduct(id);

};


Main.prototype.get = function() {
  let id = api.buildUrl(this.id.value);
  api.getProduct(id);

};

Main.prototype.getAll = function() {
  api.getAllProducts();

};

const api = new Api();
const main = new Main();


let addButton = document.getElementById('postBtn');
addButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  main.add();
});

/*
addButton.addEventListener("click",main.add.bind(main));
*/


let updateButton = document.getElementById("updateBtn");
updateButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  main.update();
});


let deleteButton = document.getElementById("deleteBtn");
deleteButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  main.delete();
});

let getButton = document.getElementById("getBtn");
getButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  main.get();
});


let getAllButton = document.getElementById("getAllBtn");
getAllButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let tst = main.getAll();
  console.log(tst);

});
```

Comment: "postman sending POST is ok. So backend is fine." Not necessarily. Using a tool like Postman does not replicate the same environment as running `fetch` in the browser. The most obvious is CORS. Open the Developer Tools in your browser and look for errors.

Comment: Tip: Since it's 2019 and ES6 is fully established there's really no reason to do the old `.prototype` style JavaScript. Unless you're explicitly supporting old Internet Explorer instances *and* you're not prepared to use a transpiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io) to bridge the gap, this is really a messy way to do what the ES6 `class` declaration does neatly.

Comment: specific one test case. if you are talking about `addButton` let us know what happen if you placed following code in the `addProduct` method first line: `console.log(id, data);`

Comment: On your gets, you need to remember the `res.json()` returns a `Promise`. so you need `[fetch code].then(res => res.json()).then(json => console.log(JSON.stringify(json)))`

Comment: It is still does not works I do not have anything in console.log ...

Comment: add function does not work

Comment: when I am clicking the add button, nothing has been added

Comment: something is incorrect maybe with scope ?